# FreeNAS 11.1 Urbackup Installation

Tags: linux, freebsd, freenas

I've been trying to install and configure [urbackup](https://www.urbackup.org/) onto a FreeNAS FreeBSD server.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/install-urbackup-in-a-jail.22117/) as well as trying to follow the instructions [here](https://www.urbackup.org/freenasserverinstall.html).

However, the first link gives me compile errors when I run:

```
$ make
$ make install
```

It returns `C++` errors about the array being ambiguous. Switching urbackup version in the `wget` command to use the 2.1.19 package and that gets further, but errors about a byte.

The second one, we manage to get through the whole list of commands but not able to access the FreeNAS server via `http://ipaddress:55414` - just returns

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Pinging the server works, ssh all works. It's just the Urbackup server doesn't actually seem to actually install correctly.

**How do I install urbackup server on FreeNAS (FreeBSM 11.1)?**

**Edit: output of netstat**

```
root@freenas[~]# netstat -4l
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address                   Foreign Address               (state)
tcp4             0           0 192.168.1.105.ssh           192.168.1.120.50139       ESTABLISHED
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.246.netbios-dgm   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.246.netbios-dgm   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.246.netbios-ns   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.246.netbios-ns   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.246.ntp           .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.255.netbios-dgm   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.248.netbios-dgm   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.255.netbios-ns   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.248.netbios-ns   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.248.ntp           .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.255.netbios-dgm   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.105.netbios-dgm   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.255.netbios-ns   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.105.netbios-ns   .
udp4             0           0 localhost.ntp                   .
udp4             0           0 192.168.1.105.ntp           .
root@freenas[~]#
```

Comment: Disable all firewalls. If this helps see this [port list](https://urbackup.atlassian.net/browse/US-45).

Comment: @harrymc didn't seem to work :s

Comment: @treyBake Can you please include the output of netstat -4l?

Comment: @JimL. see updated :)

Comment: @treyBake I have to confess to a brain fart.  I said netstat when I meant sockstat.  Also, I have no FreeNAS experience, treating this as a FreeBSD problem.  But my hunch is that the reason you can't connect is because urbackup is not listening/not running. If it IS listening, it should show up in the output of sockstat: `sockstat -4 | grep ':55414'` or simply `sockstat -4` should show the urbackup process by name and PID. I'm also not 100% clear from your post whether you did finally succeed in building from source, or whether you installed from a package via `pkg install urbackup`.

Comment: @JimL. everything is installed, as per docs linked :) steps were all followed :)

Comment: Well, you say you followed the first instructions, and you tried to follow the second instructions.  If the first instructions worked, why did you decide to follow the second instructions?  And what happened when you "tried" to follow the second instructions that prevented you from succeeding?  But rather than pull information like teeth, I'll just ...

Answer (score 3):

In testing urbackup_server on FreeBSD 11.2, I used these three commands to install, enable and start urbackup_server (and one more to check):

```
# pkg install urbackup-server
...
# sysrc urbackup_server_enable=yes
urbackup_server_enable:  -> yes
# service urbackup_server start
Starting urbackup_server.
# sockstat -4 | grep urbackup
urbackup urbackupsr 4287  6  tcp4   *:55414               *:*
urbackup urbackupsr 4287  29 udp4   10.10.231.30:35623    *:*
urbackup urbackupsr 4287  31 tcp4   *:55413               *:*
```

Troubleshooting a service that isn't responding generally follows something akin to this path:

**Is the software installed?**

You should see something like:

```
# pkg info | grep urbackup
urbackup-server-2.2.11_3     Server component of the UrBackup backup system
# grep urbackup /var/log/messages
Jan 29 10:17:12 hostname pkg[9711]: urbackup-server-2.2.11_3 installed
```

**Does the executable reside in a known location?**

```
# which urbackupsrv
/usr/local/bin/urbackupsrv
```

**Is the service enabled in /etc/rc.conf?**

```
# grep urbackup /etc/rc.conf
urbackup_server_enable="YES"
```

**Is the service running?**

```
# sockstat | grep urbackup || echo fail
fail
```

OTOH, if the service were running, you would see approximately:

```
# sockstat | grep urbackup || echo fail
urbackup urbackupsr 3992  6  tcp4   *:55414               *:*
urbackup urbackupsr 3992  29 udp4   10.10.231.30:35623    *:*
urbackup urbackupsr 3992  32 tcp4   *:55413               *:*
```

**Can the service be started?**

```
# service urbackup_server start
```

**Have you modified the stock configuration?**

If yes, restore the config file to its original state and try again.  It could be a config error or typo that's preventing startup.

**Where does the service log errors?  Can I make the logging more verbose?**

Common places are either to the syslog facility or to stderr.  The software docs should tell you.  If the service isn't starting, it's likely because the service is throwing an error.  Check those log destinations and see if the software is trying to tell you what the problem is.

**What if you attempt a manual start of the executable?**

Running the service directly from your terminal shell session sometimes offers the chance to do verbose logging, and/or logging to stderr which can be more noticeable than syslog logging.  In your specific case, many of the pertinent command-line options can be found with:

```
urbackupsrv run --help
```

If you're still stuck after looking at that documentation, I'd suggest:

```
urbackupsrv run -v debug -e -c /usr/local/etc/urbackup/urbackupsrv.conf
```

---

None of this is particularly unique to your case.  It's just good general form whenever troubleshooting an issue of this nature.  A detailed post listing the specific steps **you** followed (as opposed to the source you took them from) and the specific error message you encountered can help get results much more quickly, in part because you can demonstrate a logical flow to your troubleshooting methodology.